# MySQL UNION query, distinct IDs

Tags: mysql, distinct, union

I have two tables containing (ID, value). An ID may be found in either or both tables. I need a recordset that contains all the unique IDs with their values; if the ID occurs in both tables I need the value from table 2.

Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM table2 UNION SELECT * FROM table1) as temp
GROUP BY id
```

which appears to work. However --

1. Is this *guaranteed* to return the value from table2 if the ID is in both tables?
2. If not, how should I do it?
3. In any case, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    
        (
            SELECT *, 1 AS TB FROM table1  -- assuming you have many columns
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *, 2 AS TB FROM table2
        ) a INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID, MAX(TB) maxTB
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT ID, 1 AS TB FROM table1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ID, 2 AS TB FROM table2
            ) s
            GROUP BY ID
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.ID AND 
                a.tb = b.maxTB
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b879/2)

Comment: Thank you, that clearly works (returning the same result as my original query). Are you saying that my query is *NOT* guaranteed to return the right results?

Comment: uhmm not really but if you try to interchange the tables eg `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2`, you will certainly get invalid results.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the result I get with my testing. The point of the question is, does the order of the tables in the query *necessarily* determine the order in which the resulting values are selected (or is the result we've both obtained just an artefact of the testing methodology)? I was hoping there might be some documentation somewhere that *defined* the result. Like you, I tested the query with just a few rows in each table; but if we were dealing with thousands of rows from tables in different databases, would the order of the tables still hold?

Answer (score 0):

Putting my two cents in

```
SELECT ISNULL(TB2.Id, TB1.Id) As Id,
       ChooseValue(TB2.Id, TB2.Value, TB1.Values) As Value
FROM TABLE2 AS TB2
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE1 AS TB1
ON TB2.Id = TB1.Id
```

This avoids the cost of an extra join or an extra run through the table or the group by clause which could be expensive.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ChooseValue(DeciderValue IN VAR_TYPE, Table_2Value IN VARTYPE, Table_1Value  IN VARTYPE)
RETURNS VARTYPE
BEGIN
    DECLARE returnValue VARTYPE;
    IF DeciderValue IS NULL THEN
        returnValue = Table_2Value
    ELSE
        returnValue = Table_1Value
    END IF
RETURN returnValue
END
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach assumes that NULL is not a legitimate value. If t1 has (ID = 3, Value = X) and t2 has (ID = 3, Value = NULL) then I need the recordset to return (3, NULL).